# Is there a bijection between normal subgroups and quotient groups?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

Let $G$ be a group. Is there a bijection from the collection of all normal subgroups of $G$, $\{ N: N \trianglelefteq G \}$, to the collection of all quotient groups of $G$ by normal subgroups, $\{ G/N: N \trianglelefteq G \}$?

My attempt: I tried to consider the obvious map $f$ that sends $N$ to $G/N$. Then $f$ is clearly surjective. However, I don't know whether it is injective. If $f(N_1) = G/N_1 = G/N_2 = f(N_2)$, we want to show that $N_1 = N_2$. I tried to show the contrapositive, i.e. let's suppose that $N_1 \neq N_2$. WLOG suppose that there is $g_1 \in N_1$ but $g_1 \notin N_2$. Since $G/N_1 = G/N_2$, we know that $N_1g_1 = N_2g_2$ for some $g_2$. This is where I am stuck. I don't know if that tells me anything.

Comment: If you see the elements of a quotient $G/N$ as the cosets $Ng$ for $g \in G$, then $N$ is exactly the identity element of $G/N$. This gives you an inverse of the application $f$.

Comment: If $N_1g_1=N_2g_2$, then I believe that $N_1$ and $N_2$ must be equal. What if you relax the condition of equality of quotient groups to one of Isomorphism of quotient groups ?

Comment: @Simon Then you should probably also relax the condition of equality of normal subgroups to one of Isomorphism of groups !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The elements of $G/N_1$ are the cosets of $N_1$. Exactly one of those, namely $N_1$ itself, contains the identity element $e$ of $G$. Similarly, exactly one element of $G/N_2$, namely $N_2$ itself, contains $e$. Therefore if $G/N_1 = G/N_2$, then we would be forced to have $N_1=N_2$.

Comment: I see, because cosets partition the group, so two cosets are either equal or disjoint... so if two cosets intersect (in this case, at $e$), then they must be equal.

Comment: All of that is true, but in fact we only need a simpler set-theory argument: Suppose $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are sets of sets, and suppose $x$ is an object such that there exists a unique $S_1\in Q_1$ such that $x\in S_1$ and a unique $S_2\in Q_2$ such that $x\in S_2$. Then if $Q_1=Q_2$, we must have $S_1=S_2$.